# Does the Symfony FormServiceProvider handle a model class that is extending a base class?

Tags: php, symfony, silex

Good afternoon,

I am currently testing out the Symfony FormServiceProvider with Silex.

I have got my form built using my Model and am now trying to submit data with it.  However I have a problem the submission of it.

The model 'Content' extends the parent class 'Model'  The parent class contains the getter and setter methods to set the properties on the class.  The methods are public but the properties themselves are protected.

When I submit the form I get the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\NoSuchPropertyException: Neither the property "name" nor one of the methods "setName()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Turtle\Model\Content"
```

This happens when this section of code is run:

```
$form -> handleRequest($request);

if ($form -> isValid()) {
   // saving model data here
}
```

It seems to me that for some reason the parent class methods are not available to the 'Content' child class when Symfony is trying to turn the posted data into an object.  If this is the case does anyone know of a work around to this problem?  I do not really want to have to recreate the getters and setters in each model class.

Thanks in advance,

Russell